# Foreach works reversed in workflow parallel

Tags: .net, powershell

```
workflow test($a) {
    foreach –parallel ($item in $a){
        Write-Output $item 
   }
 }

 test ("1", "2", "3", "4")
```

Output:

```
4
3
2
1
```

Why foreach starts taking items from the end??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using -Parallel in the ForEach ...

```
workflow testStrings($a) {
    foreach ($item in $a){
        Write-Output $item 
   }
 }

testStrings ("1", "2", "3", "4")
# Results
<#
1
2
3
4
#>
```

... and as per the help files, Workflow has a Parallel implementation:

> [Windows PowerShell Workflow Concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/sma/overview-powershell-workflows?view=sc-sma-2019)
>
> Parallel Execution
>
> One advantage of Windows PowerShell Workflows is the ability to
> perform a set of commands in parallel instead of sequentially as with
> a typical script. This is particularly useful in runbooks since they
> may perform multiple actions that take a significant time to complete.
> For example, a runbook might provision a set of virtual machines.
> Rather than performing each provisioning process in sequence with one
> another, the actions could be performed simultaneously increasing
> overall efficiency. Only when all are complete would the runbook
> continue.
>
> You can use the Parallel keyword to create a script block with
> multiple commands that will run concurrently. This uses the syntax
> shown below. In this case, Activity1 and Activity2 will start at the
> same time. Activity3 will start only after both Activity1 and
> Activity2 have completed.

So, using your example:

```
workflow testStrings($a) {
    Parallel
    {
        foreach ($item in $a){
            Write-Output $item 
        }
    }
}
testStrings ("1", "2", "3", "4")
# Results
<#
1
2
3
4
#>

workflow testInt($a) {
    Parallel
    {
        foreach ($item in $a){
            Write-Output $item 
        }
    }
}
testInt (1, 2, 3, 4)
# Results
<#
1
2
3
4
#>
```

Or this segment...

> The Sequence keyword is used to run commands in sequence within a
> Parallel script block. The Sequence script block runs in parallel with
> other commands, but the commands within the block run sequentially.
> This uses the syntax shown below.
>
> In this case, Activity1, Activity2, and Activity3 will start at the
> same time.
>
> Activity4 will start only after Activity3 has completed. Activity5
> will start after all other activities have completed

```
Parallel
{
  <Activity1>
  <Activity2>

  Sequence
  {
   <Activity3>
   <Activity4>
  }
}
<Activity5>
```

Comment: In the second ur code(of 3) it will be only one activity, right?

Comment: Take a look at the doc, it's specific about the sequence thing. I just threw your code sample to stay consistent vs posting the same shown in the doc. I'll change that now to eliminate confusion for others coming upon this Q&A